# Join/union two NSManagedObjectContexts

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have one main `NSManagedObjectContext` with some entities and another background `NSManagedObjectContext` with same objects as the main `NSManagedObjectContext`. I add some objects to the background `NSManagedObjectContext` (that may exist in the main `NSManagedObjectContext`) and basically what I want is to be able to join the two `NSManagedObjectContext` instances thus making CRUD (create,read update and delete) on the objects from both `NSManagedObjectContext` instances so they're mirrored 1:1.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSManagedObjectContext` instances are just scratch pads.  They both point to the same underlying `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.  Therefore when you call `-save:` in one `NSManagedObjectContext` then the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` will get updated and you can retrieve those changes into the other `NSManagedObjectContext`.

If your "background" `NSManagedObjectContext` is a child of your "main" `NSManagedObjectContext` then just calling `-save:` on the background `NSManagedObjectContext` will cause the main `NSManagedObjectContext` to be updated automatically.  That is one of the benefits of the parent/child design.

In any case, the `NSManagedObjectContext` instances are just temporary until you save.  When you save, those changes all go to the same place; the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.